# QGIS - Serious loss of resolution when georeferecning

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf

I have a PDF which I want to georeference. I am using QGIS 3.28 and have gone to Layer > Georeferencer. However, when I load in the PDF that I want to georeference there is SIGNIFICANT  resolution loss (see the images below for reference). How do I sort this as I need the map to be of high resolution?

PDF

[image]

QGIS Georeferencer
[image]

Comment: Assuming the second image is what you see in the Georeferencer window, before you even apply a transformation and load the resulting geotiff into QGIS, keep in mind QGIS will always flatten any vector PDFs to images before loading them in Georeferencer. If your original PDF page size is small, the flattened PDF will look unacceptably pixelated when zoomed in. Consider exporting the PDF to a larger page size

Answer (score 1):

In the Output Setting box, make sure to fill in your required image resolution (in pixel dimensions) in the same units as the destination georeferenced file. If the image is in geographic degrees, you'll have to calculate more or less your required resolution.

Additional resampling and compression options may create a clearer image

[image: Output Settings]